# WebApi 2 return types

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm looking at the documentation of `WebAPI 2`, and i'm severely disappointed with the way the action results are architected. I really hope there is a better way.

So documentation says I can return these:

```
**void**    Return empty 204 (No Content)

**HttpResponseMessage** Convert directly to an HTTP response message.

**IHttpActionResult**   Call ExecuteAsync to create an HttpResponseMessage, then convert to an HTTP response message.

**Other type**  Write the serialized return value into the response body; return 200 (OK).
```

I don't see a clean way to return an array of items with custom HTTP status code,  custom headers and with auto negotiated content though.

What I would like to see is something like

```
public HttpResult<Item> Post()
{
   var item = new Item();
   var result = new HttpResult<Item>(item, HttpStatusCode.Created);
   result.Headers.Add("header", "header value");

   return result;
}
```

This way I can glance over a method and immediately see whats being returned, and modify status code and headers.

The closest thing I found is `NegotiatedContentResult<T>`, with weird signature (why does it need an instance of controller?), but there's no way to set custom headers?

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think the designers of the web-api intended for controller methods to be fiddling with the headers.
The design pattern seems to be to use [DelegatingHandler](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers), [ActionFilterAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.actionfilterattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and the ExecuteAsync overridable method of ApiController to handle authentication and response formatting.

So perhaps your logic for message content negotiation should be handled there ?

However if you definitely need to control headers from within your controller method you can do a little set-up to make it work.
To do so you can create your own DelegationHandler that forwards selected headers from your "Inner" response headers:

```cs
public class MessageHandlerBranding : DelegatingHandler {
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        //If we want to forward headers from inner content we can do this:
        if (response.Content != null && response.Content.Headers.Any())
        {
            foreach (var hdr in response.Content.Headers)
            {
                var keyUpr = hdr.Key.ToUpper(); //Response will not tolerate setting of some header values
                if ( keyUpr != "CONTENT-TYPE" && keyUpr != "CONTENT-LENGTH")
                {
                    string val = hdr.Value.Any() ? hdr.Value.FirstOrDefault() : "";
                    response.Headers.Add(hdr.Key, val);                       
                }
            }
        }
        //Add our branding header to each response
        response.Headers.Add("X-Powered-By", "My product");
        return response;
    }  
}
```

Then you register this handler in your web-api configuration, this is usually in the GlobalConfig.cs file.

```cs
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new MessageHandlerBranding());
```

You could also write your own custom class for the response object like this:

```cs
public class ApiQueryResult<T> : IHttpActionResult where T : class
{
    public ApiQueryResult(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        this.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK; ;
        this.HeadersToAdd = new List<MyStringPair>();
        this.Request = request;
    }

    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
    private List<MyStringPair> HeadersToAdd { get; set; }
    public T Content { get; set; }
    private HttpRequestMessage Request { get; set; }

    public void AddHeaders(string headerKey, string headerValue)
    {
        this.HeadersToAdd.Add(new MyStringPair(headerKey, headerValue));
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = this.Request.CreateResponse<T>(this.StatusCode, this.Content);
        foreach (var hdr in this.HeadersToAdd)
        {
            response.Content.Headers.Add(hdr.key, hdr.value); 
        }
        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }


    private class MyStringPair
    {
        public MyStringPair(string key, string value)
        {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }
        public string key;
        public string value;
    }
}
```

And use it like this in your controller:

```cs
 [HttpGet]
    public ApiQueryResult<CustomersView> CustomersViewsRow(int id)
    {
        var ret = new ApiQueryResult<CustomersView>(this.Request);
        ret.Content = this.BLL.GetOneCustomer(id);
        ret.AddHeaders("myCustomHkey","myCustomValue");
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: That ApiQueryResult should be included in the framework, imo.

Answer (score 11):

The following code should give you everything you want:

```cs
[ResponseType(typeof(Item))]
public IHttpActionResult Post()
{
    var item = new Item();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Header-Name", "Header Value");
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.Created, item);
}
```

... if you really need to return an array of items ...

```cs
[ResponseType(typeof(List<Item>))]
public IHttpActionResult Post()
{
    var items = new List<Item>();
    // Do something to fill items here...
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Item-Count", items.Count.ToString());
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.Created, items);
}
```

Comment: I hope there's a better way...
This is ugly, decorating a method with a return type ? How is it really better than just putting return type in comments?

Comment: @Eugene: The `[ResponseType]` decoration is optional, but if you want to control the response, working with `IHttpActionResult` is currently the way to do it.

Comment: This attribute appears to be respected by Swashbuckle, so it has benefits in improving API documentation.